# Is this a Django bug with annotation?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Redefining `models.query.QuerySet`.

```py
class TransactionQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet): 
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wallets = []
        wallet_transactions = self.values('wallet').annotate(amount = Sum('amount'))
        ...
        ...
```

I got:

```py
wallet_transactions = <TransactionQuerySet [{'wallet': 1, 'amount': 666}, {'wallet': 1, 'amount': 1000}, {'wallet': 1, 'amount': 500}, {'wallet': 1, 'amount': 1000}]>
```

Why aggregation in annotation doesn't work?
If you write right there:

```py
Transaction.objects.all().values('wallet').annotate(amount = Sum('amount'))
```

then everything is ok and I get:

```py
<TransactionQuerySet [{'wallet': 1, 'amount': 3166}]>
```

self и Transaction.objects.all() - return the same

```py
<TransactionQuerySet [<Transaction: Transaction: B3>, <Transaction: Transaction: B3>, <Transaction: Transaction: B2>, <Transaction: Transaction: B1>]>
```

```py
self
'SELECT "wallet_app_transaction"."id", "wallet_app_transaction"."wallet_id", "wallet_app_transaction"."amount", "wallet_app_transaction"."date", "wallet_app_transaction"."comment", "wallet_app_wallet"."id", "wallet_app_wallet"."user_id", "wallet_app_wallet"."name", "wallet_app_wallet"."balance", "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "wallet_app_transaction" INNER JOIN "wallet_app_wallet" ON ("wallet_app_transaction"."wallet_id" = "wallet_app_wallet"."id") INNER JOIN "auth_user" ON ("wallet_app_wallet"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id") WHERE "wallet_app_transaction"."id" IN (6, 5, 4) ORDER BY "wallet_app_transaction"."id" DESC'
```

```py
Transaction.objects.all()
SELECT "wallet_app_transaction"."id", "wallet_app_transaction"."wallet_id", "wallet_app_transaction"."amount", "wallet_app_transaction"."date", "wallet_app_transaction"."comment" FROM "wallet_app_transaction"
```

```py
print(self.values('wallet').annotate(amount = Sum('amount')).query)
SELECT "wallet_app_transaction"."wallet_id", SUM("wallet_app_transaction"."amount") AS "amount" FROM "wallet_app_transaction" WHERE "wallet_app_transaction"."id" IN (6, 5, 4) GROUP BY "wallet_app_transaction"."wallet_id", "wallet_app_transaction"."id" ORDER BY "wallet_app_transaction"."id" DESC
```

```py
print(Transaction.objects.all().values('wallet').annotate(amount = Sum('amount')).query)
SELECT "wallet_app_transaction"."wallet_id", SUM("wallet_app_transaction"."amount") AS "amount" FROM "wallet_app_transaction" GROUP BY "wallet_app_transaction"."wallet_id"
```

Is it a Django bug?

Comment: Let's check the equality of `all` and `self` - print both queries SQL code using `.query()` method and share results.

Comment: Done it for Transaction.objects.all() and self (selected all entries in admin)

Comment: For `all` I meant to show the query for annotation - `str(Transaction.objects.all().values('wallet').annotate(amount = Sum('amount')).query())`. In meanwhile, even for first query it's already obvious that there is no aggregation (because of no group by used). Is `self` is a queryset result from running `filter` or any other method? Because of inner join's it doesn't looks like self and `all()` are the same.

Comment: I added new data as you requested. Self is a qeryset I get when calling group delete method in django admin.

Comment: Here's the difference: `GROUP BY "wallet_app_transaction"."wallet_id", "wallet_app_transaction"."id"`, when annotation called on self. Groups will all be unique because of `"wallet_app_transaction"."id"`. Easies solution is extracting records ID's from self and then running separate query on `Transaction` with filtering first by extracted ID's, and then annotating.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Check my answer below if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a best solution, but you can try to extract ID's from queryset and then call filter on model manager using this ID's.

```py
class TransactionQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet): 
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wallets = []
        transaction_ids = list(self.values_list('id', flat=True))
        wallet_transactions = self.model.objects.filter(id__in=transaction_ids).values('wallet').annotate(amount = Sum('amount'))
```

Comment: It works, but i still don't understand why self.values('wallet').annotate(amount = Sum('amount')).query.__str__() includes an additonal field for GROUP BY "wallet_app_transaction"."id"

Comment: Id say it's because of `WHERE` clouse with filtering by PK. [Here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f5a22442176878d07e80ae5ba0af1dd8d6910fbd/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py#L165) you can read a comment to group by method used in ORM